# Eclipe Kepler crashes while opening file

Tags: crash, eclipse, workspace

When opening a file in Eclipse Kepler, the files opens for a split second and closes?? How can this be fixed?

I have tried removing `/workspace/.metadata/.lock` but it still crashes when opening a file

Answer (score 0):

Try starting eclipse in clean mode using

```
./eclipse.exe -clean
```

if that doesn't work try deleting `.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench` folder.